# using duplicate factor to plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a `ggplot_dumbbell` with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
theme_set(theme_classic())

df_senPhi <- structure(list(phi = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 1), W = c(7833625.7334, 8291583.0188, 8762978.0131, 
8169317.158, 8460793.8918, 8765222.8718, 8266025.5499, 8311199.2075, 
8265304.816, 8289392.5799, 8273733.0523, 8284554.5615), Type = c("A, B, C", 
"A, B, C", "A, B, C", "D, E", "D, E", "D, E", "F, G", "F, G", 
"H, I", "H, I", "I, J", "I, J"), pChange = c(-0.0533144181552553, 
0.00202924695507283, 0.0589968453118437, -0.0127464560859453, 
0.0224782062508261, 0.0592681341679742, -0.00105934677399903, 
0.00439984310620854, -0.00114644672167306, 0.00176453467558519, 
-0.000127903066776307, 0.00117986514708678)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), .Names = c("phi", "W", "Type", "pChange"))

df_senPhi$phi <- factor(df_senPhi$phi, levels=as.character(df_senPhi$phi))  # for right ordering of the dumbells


gg <- ggplot(df_senPhi, aes(x=0, xend=pChange, y=phi, color = Type)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(#colour="#a3c4dc",
    size=0.75, 
    colour_xend="#0e668b") + 
  scale_x_continuous(label=scales::percent)

plot(gg)
```

If you run this code, you will get a warning saying "duplicate levels in factors are deprecated".

If you look closely in the `df_senPhi` you can see 12 records. However while plotting, only 11 records are plotted. Also the `10th` and the `11th` records have the same `phi` value in the data frame which are associated in to the same level. That is also causing the overlapping of the two `phi` bars in the plot (probably that's why I'm seeing only 11 dumbbells).

I want all 12 records to be plotted such that the second `0.9` phi's dumbbell appears just above the first just like they were two different values.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: why don't you just create a helper column with different values for each row??

Comment: @Tjebo do you mean `df_senPhi$helper <- c(1:12)` and then plotting helper~pChange ?

Comment: Indeed. That's what I suggest. BTW you can also simply use 1:12 instead of c(1:12). Also , instead of hardcoding the vector, you could (and should) use 1: nrow(your_data frame)

Comment: You can try `factor(df_senPhi$phi, levels=unique(as.character(df_senPhi$phi)))` to create your factors. You need a list of unique values for the levels.

Comment: @steveb that just eliminates the warning. it creates unique levels so both 0.9 would be treated the same. That is a good thing but doesnot solve my problem. I still get 11 plots.

Comment: @anup I was only attempting to get rid of the warning, which is why is why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Tjebo  yes. I tried that and it worked. Now I have 1:12 on the y-axis but I could easily use `scale_y_discrete(labels = df_senPhi$phi)` and got what I needed. Thanks! So dumb of me not to think of a new helper column.

Answer (score 0):

used a bit of `dplyr`

but it seems to get what you are looking for

```
df_senPhi %>% 
  mutate(row = 1:n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(0, row, color = Type)) +
  geom_dumbbell(aes(xend = pChange)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = factor(df_senPhi$phi),
                     breaks = 1:12)
```